# Как в Golang экранировать %?

Tags: golang

Добрый день, есть sql запрос

```
query="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Begin, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i') as Begin ... from table where id= %d"
```

Я подставляю в id нужное значение. Но, когда добавляю `DATE_FORMAT(Begin, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i') as Begin`  - то,т.к. там тоже есть %-он сходит с ума. Я пробовал их экранировать /% ,но это не работает.
Нужно,что б sql был именно с % ,но в тоже время, что б golang подставил значение в id= %d . Подскажите, как это сделать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`%` экранируется как `%%`:

```
query="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Begin, '%%d.%%m.%%Y %%H:%%i') as Begin ... from table where id= %d"
```

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало)))